# How to edit and run the nav2d tutorial

Tags: ros, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to edit the launch file by following tutorials for nav2d. So at the beginning I have download the package from github: https://github.com/skasperski/navigation_2d and past it in my catkin_ws, and run `make`
Afterword when I try to run the one of the tutorials then it complain this:

`roslaunch nav2d_tutorials tutorial2.launch`

` multiple files named [tutorial2.launch] in package [nav2d_tutorials]:

- /opt/ros/indigo/share/nav2d_tutorials/launch/tutorial2.launch
- /home/hjt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d-master/nav2d_tutorials/launch/tutorial2.launch
  Please specify full path instead
  The traceback for the exception was written to the log file`

Then I tried to write the path but it did not work
`roslaunch nav2d_tutorials /home/hjt/catkin_ws/src/navigation_2d-master/nav2d_tutorials/launch/tutorial2.launch`

What should I do, so I'm able to run the simulation with edited launch files ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225552/how-to-edit-and-run-the-nav2d-tutorial/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have both the binary version (in /opt/ros/indigo/...) and the source version (in /home/hjt/catkin_ws/src/...) installed. So make sure you build using catkin so the source version can correctly override the binary version.

```
cd /home/hjt/catkin_ws
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
catkin_make
source /home/hjt/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Now after you build your workspace, you always have to source the setup.bash from this workspace in order to use it, not the one from /opt/ros/...
Try this first, because as far as I know it should be no problem to have a package both as binary and source installed. Only if it doesn't work, try uninstalling the nav2d-binaries.

And yes, you shouldn't manually change anything in /opt/ros/.... But it is no problem to remove packages using the package manager of your choice (e.g. Synaptic) or just apt-get on the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-indigo-nav2d
```

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-02-01**:
Unfortunately it did not worked even when I run `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and then catkin_make

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-02-02**:
Have you tried un-installing the binary version?

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-02-02**:
No,because I have been told that I should not touch or edit anything in ROS installation folder!
And I'm not sure how to un-install all nav2d packages so it dos not have any influence on other thing?

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-02-02**:
Thank you so much Sebastian for helping, I'm now able to run the simulation from my catkin_ws. I'm just missing the Robot icon in the RVIZ simulation but that is maybe because of I'm using Ros Indigo and as you mentioned befor that URDF was not supported.